# How to map collections in Hibernate to PostgreSQL DB, without using any mapping table?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, playframework-2.0

I want to store String[] tags in my table "Store". A  store entity can have multiple tags, and I don't see any reason to create any mapping "`store_tags`" table.

All relevant tags should be stored in "Store" table. From what I can search on Internet it seems  JPA/Hibernate `@ElementCollection` annotation does that, but it needs Collection Mapping table.

Is it possible to store and retrieve data as `String[]` in postgresql table, through hibernate, without creating any such mapping table ?

Also if thats not possible, would concatenating String list into a string and storing it in table, be acceptable design? Or will it have any bad consequences? Please give few examples/points where these options might cause problem in future.

I am using Java Play Framework, Hibernate and PostgreSQL.

Comment: You could follow your own suggestion of using a delimited list. You'd have to code logic to build and split the list when you're storing it and retrieving it, respectfully. One downside may be that you'd lose lazy loading, if the lists may be large. You also may not be able to enforce uniqueness at the DB level (would need to be done in code). Have you tried this approach?

Comment: @SaadShakil No I haven't tried it, wanted to know pros and cons of this approach, before implementing it. My list would not be more than 100 words, so I think lazy initialization would not be issue in my case. Thanks for your prompt response !

Comment: The point of using a table is to make your data searchable: look for a store which has a given tag, or which has a given set of tags for example. Use proper database design instead of shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @JBNizet I totally agree with you, what I can't understand is why can't I just store collection in DB through JPA, without using mapping table. I think in many cases mapping table is irrelevant, and using it will cause data redundancy and slow down query. If suppose I have to first filter stores based on locality and then filter it based on tags. Then having tags in "store" table would increase the query speed rather than joining the data with mapping table. IMHO even if I store it in comma separated single string, querying this sub result using LIKE command would be much faster.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. A join is more efficient than a like query, which can't use any index and thus needs a full scan. And I'm not even talking of cases where a comma is part of the tag name, and must thus be escaped. Or the case of tags which are substrings of other tags, etc. Storing tags in a separate table will *avoid* redundancy: instead of storing long tag names again and again, you will store them once, in a single row, and refer to them via their numeric ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to avoid using a separate table for the store_tag relation, then you might consider `hstore` support with PostgreSL. However, you need to use a UserType implementation with hibernate (not part of core hibernate). So, Handling with hibernate might be inconvenient to painful. Just storing and retrieving tags might be OK. Using tags with other aspects might be a strong argument towards using a separate table.

As always, I would analyze the common query and modification use cases. And explicitly *measure* performance effects from both variants.